# Detaching an attachment in Mutt

Tags: mutt

Once I've attached a file to an email in Mutt, I can't find a way to detach it again.  Surely there must be one?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `D` (uppercase) to remove the attachment under the cursor.

Comment: First type `v` to view the message structure including attachments. `$` will then execute the deletion.

Comment: @Juancho I think the question is about the Compose screen, not the Pager view.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without downloading (over IMAP, in my case) the whole message, with its giant attachment?